# Stock code request application in Django & SQL

Tags: python, django, stock

I have a material excelfile and it has different type of material.
Each category has start specific prefix like **AB**001 or **BC**001

I am planning to write a webservice for the request of this material stock codes.

But I need to import the my old database and i have stucked how can i implement this?

I have created a model in DJANGO like Materials, But i could not solve that if i import the my old excel file, the software how can understand the numbers will be correct.
It must be consecutively. Like ( **AB**001 , **AB**002, **AC**001,**AC**002,**AZ**001)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values (AB001, AB002, etc) your intended primary keys? Or are they just identifiers that can be a separate field? In case of the former, look into overriding `save` method and using a custom primary key field on Django models.

Answer (score 1):

Django ORM has an `order_by()` method. do you need something other than this?

The models meta class can allow for default order

**models.py**

```
class Material(models.Model):
    material_stock_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['material_stock_code']
```

The `order_by()` method can be used on any query
**views.py**

```
Material.objects.all().order_by('material_stock_code')
```

I would also recommend looking at django-rest-framework to make the API

Comment: Uh, so sorry my respond is really late. Yes i have looked this kind of solution. Thanks a lot!